# No spaces, top position: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I read a lot of discussion and I know very well that ila function session_start () must be placed top of the page and in fact is what I do and yet the error message always appears.
I also tried to save files with notepad but still nothing.
Below we show simple file that triggered the error.

## Error Message

```
session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /customers/9/7/f/xxxx.com/httpd.www/ito2/ito-admin/login.php:1) in /customers/9/7/f/xxxx.com/httpd.www/ito2/ito-admin/library.php on line 2
```

## login.php

```
  <?php
  include 'library.php';
  if(isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['userid'] != ''){ 
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "index.php";      </script>';
 //exit(header('location:index.php'));
 }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <title>SicilyTrip</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Animate.css -->
<link href="https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Theme Style -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#username').focus(); 
$('#login').click(function(){ 
    var username = $('#username'); 
    var password = $('#password'); 
    var login_result = $('.login_result'); 
    login_result.html('caricamento...'); 
    if(username.val() == ''){ 
        username.focus(); 
        login_result.html('<span class="error">Inserisci Username</span>');
        return false;
    }
    if(password.val() == ''){ 
        password.focus();
        login_result.html('<span class="error">Inserisci Password</span>');
        return false;
    }
    if(username.val() != '' && password.val() != ''){ 
        var UrlToPass = 'action=login&username='+username.val()+'&password='+password.val();
        $.ajax({ 
        type : 'POST',
        data : UrlToPass,
        url  : 'checker.php',
        success: function(responseText){ 
            if(responseText == 0){
                login_result.html('<span class="error">Username o Password errati!</span>');
            }
            else if(responseText == 1){
                window.location = 'benvenuto.php';
            }
            else{
                alert('Riscontrato problema SQL');
            }
        }
        });
    }
    return false;
   });
  });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
 body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: arial;
 color: #2C2C2C;
 font-size: 14px;
 }
 h1 a{
 color:#2C2C2C;
 text-decoration:none;
 }
 h1 a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
 }
.as_wrapper{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1000px;
 }
.mytable{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 20px;
border:2px dashed #05A9C5;
}
.as_login_heading{
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:left;
font-size:18px;
}
.success{
color:#009900;
}
.error{
color:#F33C21;
}
.talign_left{
text-align:left;
}
.as_input{
border:0;
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding:5px;
width:180px;
border:#05A9C5 solid 1px;
}
.as_input:hover{
border:#321363 solid 1px;
}
.as_input.error{
border:#ed1846 solid 1px;
}
.as_button{
background:#05A9C5;
border:none;
outline:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:#FFF;
padding:5px 10px;
font-weight:300;
cursor:pointer;
}
.as_button:hover{
background:#036576;
}
.as_button:active{
background:#a1147d;
}
.login_result{
display:block;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
height:25px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body class="login">
<div>
  <a class="hiddenanchor" id="signup"></a>
  <a class="hiddenanchor" id="signin"></a>

  <div class="login_wrapper">
    <div class="animate form login_form">
      <section class="login_content">
        <form>
          <h1>Login </h1>
          <div class="login_result" id="login_result"></div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="as_input" placeholder="Username" required="" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="as_input" placeholder="Password" required="" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-default submit" value="Login &raquo;" />
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div class="separator">
            <div>
              <h1>xxxxxxx</h1>
              <p>©2016 All Rights Reserved. SicilyTrip</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
         </section>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## library.php

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION,$_POST,$_COOKIE,__FILE__,__LINE__); // @RyanVincent
mysql_connect("xxxxxx.com.mysql", "xxxxxx", "xxxxx") or die ("Oops! Server non collegato");
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxx") or die ("Oops! Database non connesso");
?>
```

**someone tell me where I'm wrong?**

This is answer after insert debugging line:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /customers/9/7/f/xxxxxx.com/httpd.www/ito2/ito-admin/login.php:1) in /customers/9/7/f/xxxxxxx.com/httpd.www/ito2/ito-admin/library.php on line 2
array(0) { } array(0) { }
array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "rnoue0fq4o0d4kiuf9vqrque85"}
string(68) "/customers/9/7/f/xxxxxx.com/httpd.www/ito2/ito-admin/library.php" int(3)
```

## UPDATE response with Online HexDump Utility at

http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm

```
 file name: library.php
 mime type: 

 0000-0010:  3c 3f 70 68-70 0d 0a 73-65 73 73 69-6f 6e 5f 73  <?php..s ession_s
 0000-0020:  74 61 72 74-28 29 3b 0d-0a 76 61 72-5f 64 75 6d  tart();. .var_dum
 0000-0030:  70 28 24 5f-53 45 53 53-49 4f 4e 2c-24 5f 50 4f  p($_SESS ION,$_PO
 0000-0040:  53 54 2c 24-5f 43 4f 4f-4b 49 45 2c-5f 5f 46 49  ST,$_COO KIE,__FI
 0000-0050:  4c 45 5f 5f-2c 5f 5f 4c-49 4e 45 5f-5f 29 3b 0d  LE__,__L INE__);.
 0000-0060:  0a 6d 79 73-71 6c 5f 63-6f 6e 6e 65-63 74 28 22  .mysql_c onnect("
 0000-0070:  73 69 63 69-6c 79 74 72-69 70 2e 63-6f 6d 2e 6d  xxxxxxxx ip.com.m
 0000-0080:  79 73 71 6c-22 2c 20 22-73 69 63 69-6c 79 74 72  ysql",." xxxxxxxx
 0000-0090:  69 70 5f 63-6f 6d 22 2c-20 22 55 7a-5a 33 5a 36  ip_com", ."xxxxxx
 0000-00a0:  53 55 22 29-20 6f 72 20-64 69 65 20-28 22 4f 6f  xx").or. die.("Oo
 0000-00b0:  70 73 21 20-53 65 72 76-65 72 20 6e-6f 6e 20 63  ps!.Serv er.non.c
 0000-00c0:  6f 6c 6c 65-67 61 74 6f-22 29 3b 0d-0a 6d 79 73  ollegato ");..mys
 0000-00d0:  71 6c 5f 73-65 6c 65 63-74 5f 64 62-28 22 73 69  ql_selec t_db("xx
 0000-00e0:  63 69 6c 79-74 72 69 70-5f 63 6f 6d-22 29 20 6f  xxxxxx_com").o
 0000-00f0:  72 20 64 69-65 20 28 22-4f 6f 70 73-21 20 44 61  r.die.(" Oops!.Da
 0000-0100:  74 61 62 61-73 65 20 6e-6f 6e 20 63-6f 6e 6e 65  tabase.n on.conne
 0000-010a:  73 73 6f 22-29 3b 0d 0a-3f 3e                    sso");.. ?>


file name: login.php
mime type: 

0000-0010:  ef bb bf 3c-3f 70 68 70-0d 0a 70 0d-0a 69 6e 63  ...<?php inc
0000-0020:  6c 75 64 65-5f 6f 6e 63-65 20 27 6c-69 62 72 61  lude_onc e.'libra
0000-0030:  72 79 2e 70-68 70 27 3b-0d 0a 69 66-28 69 73 73  ry.php'; ..if(iss
0000-0040:  65 74 28 24-5f 53 45 53-53 49 4f 4e-5b 27 75 73  et($_SES SION['us
0000-0050:  65 72 69 64-27 5d 29 20-26 26 20 24-5f 53 45 53  erid']). &&.$_SES
0000-0060:  53 49 4f 4e-5b 27 75 73-65 72 69 64-27 5d 20 21  SION['us erid'].!
......................................
0000-11a0:  20 20 20 20-20 20 20 20-3c 2f 73 65-63 74 69 6f  ........ </sectio
0000-11b0:  6e 3e 0d 0a-20 20 20 20-20 20 20 20-3c 2f 64 69  n>...... ....</di
0000-11c0:  76 3e 0d 0a-20 20 20 20-20 20 3c 2f-64 69 76 3e  v>...... ..</div>
0000-11d0:  0d 0a 20 20-20 20 3c 2f-64 69 76 3e-0d 0a 20 20  ......</ div>....
0000-11e0:  3c 2f 62 6f-64 79 3e 0d-0a 3c 2f 68-74 6d 6c 3e  </body>. .</html>
```

The problem was in the first few characters of the login.php
Thanks to @RyanVincent and @DaveChen suggestion I've uploaded the file to convert it into ASCII characters and have come out of these characters before the

Thank you all...

Comment: session_start(); should be placed at the top in login.php, before include 'library.php'. You also need to make sure that there is no echo/print output in library.php

Comment: @CodeCodeO-1-O-log-n It is included at the beginning through the library file that I inserted in the post to make you see that it is clearly free from space

Comment: make sure your changes are taking effect too. for example, check if your php code is being cached.

Comment: @CodeCodeO-1-O-log-n I cleared the cache but nothing yet.

Comment: @RyanVincent 
I removed the closing PHP tags from index.php and library.php but still nothing. Does not work.

Comment: `Does not work?` You have `display_errors E_ALL` on so you can see every message from PHP? How are you going to debug this? We cannot do it for you unless we have an example we can run. Amd you do not provide enough detail to explain in what order your files run. Example: what url do you use to run your script. How do you execute `login.php`. I run : `http:://localhost/login.php` to test my login script. How do you run `login.php`? Useful  information? Do you even show us the script you use to run 'login.php'? without this information then we and you are guessing?

Comment: session_start() can not be placed in an included file.  See the documentation for more info...

Comment: @dalearn Are you sure? 
I've already put in other projects the session_start command in include files, and I never had problems.

Comment: @RyanVincent This is the answer to the debugging of the variables that you suggested:Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /customers/9/7/f/xxxxxx.com/httpd.www/ito2/ito-admin/login.php:1) in /customers/9/7/f/xxxxxx.com/httpd.www/ito2/ito-admin/library.php on line 2 array(0) { } array(0) { } array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "rnoue0fq4o0d4kiuf9vqrque85" } string(68) "/customers/9/7/f/xxxxxxx.com/httpd.www/ito2/ito-admin/library.php" int(7)

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm sorry I edited the question with the response results.

Comment: @RyanVincent 
No unfortunately not ..... :-( 
I added the debugging line library.php after session_start () I edited the question to reflect the real situation.

Comment: Is it possible that your encoding is UTF-8 with BOM? You need to encode without BOM. http://i.imgur.com/LJuMspK.png

Comment: @DaveChen I also checked this previously. Use Codelobster and saves in UTF-8 without BOM ...

Comment: yes, some web hosts have it configured so that you can but technically you can't...  :(

Comment: Wait so are you testing this locally on your own machine or is this with a shared host/free hosting? There's a chance the issue is on their side and you'll need to contact them.

Comment: You really need to pay attention to that error message. That is PHP trying to help you. I would hex edit the source files to ensure they are correct. Seriously, invalid source files will cause days of debugging. what I would do? copy and paste the source files into an ASCII text editor. Save it run it. PHP is really trying to help you with that error message. Please pay attention to it. I would.

Comment: @DaveChen No ..... it includes use on this same server in other parts of the project and it works ... So the problem is not the server.

Comment: I'm really suspecting that there's a BOM or something at the beginning of the file. Can you [upload your file here](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm) (or use a hexdump util) and see what the beginning looks like? If it starts with `ef bb bf` then you know you have an issue. See the hex dump for both library.php and one of your other affected files.

Comment: maybe interesting: [HexDump - Online hex viewer](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm). there are others...

Comment: @DaveChen Thank You! See update question.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thank You! See update question.

Comment: What happens when you take session_start(); out of library.php and make it the very first thing in login.php? For good measure remove any spacing so that it begins as: <?php session_start();

Comment: If that works, then check the very top of login.php -- make sure it reads: "<?php include 'library.php';" all in one line no spaces.